# With regards to PDEs, what is the difference between an initial condition and a boundary condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

With regards to PDEs, what is the difference between an initial condition and a boundary condition?

I am given the following examples.

An example of an initial condition is $u(x,0) = \sin(x)$ $\forall$ $x$.

An example of a boundary condition is $u(0,t) = e^{-t}$ $\forall$ $t > 0$.

However, these examples are not telling me anything general about the difference between an initial condition and a boundary condition for PDEs. I would like someone to explain this difference in a general way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is in the name. An initial condition is fixing the value when $t=0$ and a boundary condition is fixing the value on some spatial boundary. There's nothing particularly deep about the definition.

For example if you had the wave equation on a string, an initial condition would be starting a wave at $t=0$ and a boundary condition would be holding the ends of the string.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to say that the boundary is all values of $t > 0$? There is obviously no upper boundary in this case? I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @ThePointer  A boundary in this case has to do with a spatial boundary, not a time boundary.

Comment: I see. Can you please give a practical example of a spatial boundary in this situation?

Comment: @ThePointer There's one in my answer

Comment: Oh ok, this makes sense. Thank you!